# how to open my app by clicking on links of my website

Tags: android, url, webview

I have a website and I have an simple app that have a simple webview.

When everybody has installed app they can click on links to my website. Those then should open in my app.

For example if my website is `www.zoomit.ir` and i click on `https://www.zoomit.ir/2016/10/8/146994/todoist-tasklist-mobile-app/` in an social app like insta or telegram open my app and show that link

how to lunch app and get that link and show that in webview

Comment: There is a documentation at official page https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, try adding an intent filter in your `<activity>` which you want to open from the link

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

<data
    android:host="www.zoomit.ir"
    android:scheme="http"></data>

</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

assuming `www.zoomit.ir` is the link which should open the app

Inorder to open this url in webview first get this url by using intent in your activity's `onCreate`

```
    String url;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

 if (data!=null) {     
 webView.loadUrl(data.getScheme()+"://"+data.getHost()+data.getPath());
    }
```

Now you will have `url`="www.zoomit.ir/example-post". Use this `url` to load webview

Comment: i want to do this for other links of my website like that i wrote in my question ....

Comment: just replace with that link

Comment: tnx but i want open my app by clicking on all links that is start with zoomit.ir/example-post

Comment: add `android:pathPrefix="example-post"` in your `<data>`, see updated answer

Comment: With this patch prefix option ...my app runs and open that link in webview?

Comment: no, on clicking this link (www.zoomit.ir/example-post), it should open up your app

Comment: @Stonefist24 if it didnt work ,try removing `android:path="launch"`

Comment: What can i do to open exact links? @ヅ fix

Comment: @Stonefist24 inorder to open the specified url in manifest, get the url using intent in your activity's oncreate, see updated answer

Comment: remove `android:pathPrefix="/example-post"` so that you can load any url like www.zoomit.ir/abc,www.zoomit.ir/xyz etc

Comment: dosent work...can u send me an ready source :(